# Problems with Bidirectional LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

Initially I used a LSTM with two hidden layers then decided to see if using a Bidirectional layer would have any improvements. I made no changes to the shape of the input from LSTM to Bidirectional LSTM. When I run the LSTM version it runs just fine but when I run the Bidirectional version I get an error about the second layer expecting 4 dimensions. My question is why is this happening and what can I do?

> Error Message : ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

The input shape of the training set is `(284,1,3)`.

Code for Bidirectional LSTM:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=steps,input_shape=(1,steps))))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(steps),merge_mode= 'ave'))
model.add(LSTM(units=steps,return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd',metrics=[Gavg])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs= 200, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are stacking multiple LSTM layers on top of each other, you need to use `return_sequences=True` on the first two layers. Otherwise, their output would have a shape of `(batch_size, n_units)` and therefore would not be a sequence and cannot be processed by the following LSTM layer.